# Kernel Density Estimation Heatmap in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, kernel-density

I have a list of latitude and longitude coordinates and respective Received Signal strength values at each coordinate. How would I plot a kernel density estimation (kde) 2D heatmap for these signal strengths at each lat-lon in python(matplotlib)?

Comment: It's unclear if you have researched or tried something before posting here

Answer (score 4):

You can use the python library **seaborn**. It has a handy function that plots kernel density estimation for your heatmaps.

Check this out :

```
import seaborn as sns

lat = [list_of_values]
long = [list_of_values]
ax = sns.kdeplot(lat, long, cmap="Blues", shade=True, shade_lowest=False)
```