# How can I plot heatmap of Wi-Fi signal strength in a 2-D surface?

Tags: matlab, plot, heatmap

I've my dataset as follows (for instance):

```
strength = [-90 -90 -90 -90 -40 -20 -22.4 -45 -35 -41 -44 -55 -40 -75 -26]
X = [10 550 550 10 50 234 393 129 237 328 448 225 344 457 477]
Y = [10 10 410 410 293 210 202 132 130 142 141 272 268 274 200]
```

Here, `strength` is the received signal strength in dBm, X and Y are 2-D coordinates. I want to plot the heatmap of the signal strength at all the coordinate points.

My situation is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748477/kernel-density-estimation-heatmap-in-python/39748978#39748978) question. However, I want to plot the received signal strength and in Matlab, as shown in the attached figure (because of picture quality). A solution in Matlab is found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/thingspeak/create-heatmap-overlay-image.html), however, the code given in the link does not work. The Command Window of Matlab displays *HeatMap object with 0 rows and 0 columns*. The available code in Matlab is as follows:

```
strength = [-90 -90 -90 -90 -40 -20 -22.4 -45 -35 -41 -44 -55 -40 -75 -26]';
X = [10 550 550 10 50 234 393 129 237 328 448 225 344 457 477]';
Y = [10 10 410 410 293 210 202 132 130 142 141 272 268 274 200]';
strengthPercent = 2*(strength+100)/100;
picture = imread('https://www.mathworks.com/help/examples/thingspeak/win64/CreateHeatmapOverlayImageTSExample_02.png'); 
[height,width,depth] = size(picture);
OverlayImage=[];
F = scatteredInterpolant(Y, X, strengthPercent,'linear');
for i = 1:height-1
   for j = 1:width-1
          OverlayImage(i,j) = F(i,j);
   end
end
alpha = (~isnan(OverlayImage))*0.6;

imshow(picture);
hold on
OverlayImage = imshow( OverlayImage );
caxis auto  
colormap( OverlayImage.Parent, jet );
colorbar( OverlayImage.Parent );
set( OverlayImage, 'AlphaData', alpha );
```

Any suggestions, please!

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] the post to also include a [mcve], because now we cannot see how you plotted the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scatteredInterpolant` as in the code you showed, just pair it with `surf`

```
F = scatteredInterpolant(X(:), Y(:), strength(:));
[XD, Yd] = meshgrid( 0:10:410, 0:10:550 );
Zd = F( XD, Yd );
surf( XD, Yd, Zd, 'EdgeColor', 'interp' );
view([0,90]); % view 3D plot from above
```

You can change the `colormap` to customise the appearance.

```
colormap( 'hot' );
colorbar();
```

You should be able to reduce the `FaceAlpha` of the surface to lay it over an image.